# Determine colour, alpha of a point in a UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview

Is there any way to query a UIImageView to see what is at any given point? For example, user touches at a particular point, what's the colour of the pixel in the under the touch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could draw the image from the image view to a CGBitmapContext which your app has allocated, and then read the RGBA bytes at the appropriate offset within the bitmap, computed from the XY touch location, and bitmap rowbytes.  Then compute the color as needed from the RGBA byte values.

For efficiency, you might be able to draw only a tiny sub rectangle of your image into a tiny bitmap (1x1 pixel?).